# Why does the div get misaligned if I add position:absolute (css) within a position:relative div?

Tags: css, html, frontend

I'm learning HTML/CSS and I encountered a problem. I'm currently working on goodwill.heyscout.com as a side project.

From learnlayout.org, I learned that the best way to structure a layout with a div is to give the inner a position:absolute, and the outer a position:relative. This works.

However, this throws the alignment off as soon as I add the position:absolute (I want the profile cards side-by-side). Without the position absolute, everything gets shifted if I want to alter the layout of the profile card. As you can see on the bottom two profile cards, they align as those aren't altered.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? 
I also know that my code is pretty messy and that's what I really need to get better at... any other suggestions on how I can improve my code would also be useful.

Comment: Please add some of the relevant code to your question. Specifically the HTML structure and the CSS for those items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can throw a `float: left` onto your `outer` class and that should get them sitting side by side again. You may want to read up on using floats at some point as they can be very powerful (if a little hard to get your head around at first)

```
.outer {
    width: 49%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

BTW, I notice you using `id="outer"` multiple times. You should change this to `class="outer"` as an ID should be unique, whereas a class can be used multiple times. You'll see in the above CSS that I've used `.outer` as I'm targeting by a class name (rather than `#outer` which targets by ID)

Comment: Adding `vertical-align: top` instead of `float: left` also solves the issue. In case the OP wants to avoid floating the elements.

Comment: Thank you! I always wondered when you use class and when you use id so that was super useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem you have found. I can't tell you exactly why it is behaving this way but it appears to be related to having text directly in the #box div or not. If you remove the "test" from the second one it aligns as you would expect. Likewise, if you put the exact same content in the second div as the first, they align.

For improvements I would start by never re-using an id (like you are doing with #outer and #box for example, these should be classes). The id attribute needs to be unique, no two DOM-elements should have the same id.

I would also suggest using a ul for #businesscards sice it represents a list of cards. This would make #outer an li. You did this in #navlist so you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Give just `vertical-align: top;` to your `#outer` div. The problem will be solved.

As this happens only to child elements, give something like this to solve the issue:

```
div > * {  /* or just  '*' */
    vertical-align: top; /* or middle */
}
```